# Posgres - Order by field within JSONB array?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Here is my data sample of my jsonb field `itineraries` in a row of my table `trips`:

```
[
    {
        "nights": 10,
        "destinations": [
            "Cronaside",
            "New Emory",
            "East Mattiechester"
        ],
        "departure_date_end": "2020-09-21",
        "return_date_latest": "2020-10-01",
        "departure_date_start": "2020-09-14"
    },
    {
        "nights": 10,
        "destinations": [
            "Port Verdie",
            "Chaunceymouth",
            "Isabellemouth"
        ],
        "departure_date_end": "2020-10-08",
        "return_date_latest": "2020-10-18",
        "departure_date_start": "2020-09-14"
    }
]
```

My aim is to return rows from `trips` ordered by the earliest `departure_date_start` of this jsonb field `itineraries`. Here is my simple attempt:

```
SELECT * 
from trips
ORDER BY itineraries->>'departure_date_start' ASC
```

However, because  `itineraries` is an array and can have multiple `departure_date_start` values, does Postgres handle this automatically? Or am I required to loop over the array?

Using Postgres 9.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to expand the array.

```
select t.*
  from trips t
 cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(t.itineraries) as i(datel)
 order by i.datel->>'departure_date_start';
```

This will return multiple rows per trip.

If you want to limit the result to only one row per trip, then you can group by the columns you are returning like so:

```
select t.id, t.some_col, t.some_other_column, t.itineraries, 
       min(i.datel->>'departure_date_start') as departure_date_start
  from trips t
 cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(t.itineraries) as i(datel)
 group by t.id, t.some_col, t.some_other_column, t.itineraries
 order by min(i.datel->>'departure_date_start')
```

Comment: Mike, can I ask how I can only retrieve distinct values for this query? Currently it's returning duplicate rows.

Comment: @f7n  I added a `group by` example that will eliminate duplicates.